# How do I parameterize test cases in TypeScript unit tests?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocha.js, fixtures

I have a simple passing unit test:

```
describe("Example", () => {
    it("Return digits or empty string", () => {
        let actual = SmokeTest.ProblemOne("1");
        assert.equal(actual, "1");
    })
})
```

I now wish to test many other cases (empty string, more complex inputs and edge-cases). I have [read about how to implement fixtures in TypeScript](https://michalzalecki.com/fixtures-the-way-to-manage-sample-and-test-data/) but this seems like overkill for an array of `test-input, expected-output` values.

What is the idiomatic way to define such an array in TypeScript / Mocha?

Comment: other frameworks like TestyTs use recognizable constructs https://github.com/Testy/TestyTs#test-cases

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[From the Mocha documentation](https://mochajs.org/#dynamically-generating-tests):

> No special syntax is required... to parameterize tests [you can] generate them with a closure.

```js
describe("Example", () => {

    // define a closure that calls the method we are testing
    const testProblemOne = ({arg, expected}) =>
        function () {
            const actual = SmokeTest.ProblemOne(arg);
            assert.equal(actual, expected);
        }

    // invoke the closure for each test case
    it("Empty returns empty", testProblemOne({arg: "", expected: ""}));
    it("Single digit identity", testProblemOne({arg: "1", expected: "1"}));
    // additional test cases here...
})
```

This technique avoids using `foreach` in favor of readability and broader IDE integration.

Answer (score 0):

You can just make a function that you can reuse.

```
function assertProblemOne(input: string, expected: string): void {
    let actual = SmokeTest.ProblemOne(input);
    assert.equal(expected, actual);
}

describe("Example", () => {
    it("Return digits or empty string", () => {
        assertProblemOne("input here", "expected result here")
    })
})
```

However, I'm not sure that's really much better than simply.

```
assert.equal(SmokeTest.ProblemOne("1"), "1");
```

The only thing worse than debugging your code is debugging your tests. So unless there is a large amount of code that is shared between tests, I would recommend keep the code that runs in each tests as structurally simple as possible.

Comment: I've been given feedback that a list of asserts in a single unit test is not acceptable (at least amongst the Python developers I know) - is it possibly more common in the JS/TS world? or maybe my example is too simple :)

Comment: Your example has an N of one, so there's nothing common to abstract. So yes, I think your example is too simple and it's hard to advise much of anything concrete.